# How to make camera move along the view direction in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I was trying to write a flight simulator in WebGL with handler of keyboard event. The camera should always move along the view direction after various rotations.

I tried to maintain a velocity vector by doing the rotation of this vector after rotate the whole mvMatrix and call

```
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, velocity);
```

To make it move at a constant speed and it does work.

However, after I rolled and pitched, it still move along the initiated direction.

Is there any way to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The view direction of your camera should be it's Z-Axis. (if you stick with gl-matrix convention).

```
// on init
// -------
var camMatrix = mat4.create()// the camera matrix

// zAxis : third row (z) of cam matrix;
var zAxis    = new Float32Array( camMatrix.buffer, 32, 3 );
// position : fourth row
var position = new Float32Array( camMatrix.buffer, 48, 3 );

// on update
// ---------
var velocity = 3.0 // scalar value

// move the cam along zaxis
vec3.scaleAndAdd( position, position, zAxis,  velocity );
```

Comment: Should I multiply this matrix with mvMatrix in shader?